# Get prefix from Netherlands names

Tags: python, django

I have a social network with users from the Netherlands on Django.
With my site I can get the Netherlands name, for example, **Jap van der Stael**, and I need to get only **van der** part. For this name it's not a problem, but how to get infix from a name like **Jap van der Vulpen - Odijk**?

For now i have next code:

```
last_name_1 = 'van der Vulpen'
last_name_2 = 'van der Vulpen - Odijk'

' '.join(last_name_1.split()[:-1] -> 'van der'
' '.join(last_name_2.split()[:-1] -> 'van der Vulpen -'
```

How to return clear prefix for last_name_2

Some possible examples of the names:

```
nijveldt - affourtit -> ''
van Eldik -> 'van'
deHart -> 'de'
NIEUWBURG -> ''
Heuvel van den -> 'van den'
van deven -. 'van'
Koerten - de Jong -> 'de'
vanBARNEVELD -> 'van'
```

Comment: If you'd like to ask a Python question, it'd be great if you could [edit] your post to include the Python code you've written thusfar

Comment: Names in the Netherlands can get rather complicated, especially when there's a double name from a marriage with a person from another country with similarly complicated naming systems (Germany, Spain, Portugal,...). So, how many edge cases are you prepared to handle?

Comment: Please include the expected output for everything in that list because I'm not sure how to interpret all those.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that in the Netherlands those middle parts are always lowercase. So, this should work:

```
def get_prefix(name):
    return " ".join([x for x in name.split(" ") if x.islower()])
```

The nice thing about this solution is that "-" does not count as being lowercase so it is filtered out as well. However, if the "proper" parts of the name are not uppercase then we have a problem. To fix this, we'll have to consider the string as a whole:

```
def get_prefix_v2(name):
    parts = name.split(" ")
    i = len(parts) - 2
    while i >= 0:
        if parts[i] == "-":
            i -= 2
        else:
            return " ".join(parts[1:i+1])
```

However, this function still assumes that you have a first name and last name. Another thing you could consider is finding valid prefix values and pulling it out that way:

```
valid_prefix_parts = set(["van", "de", "den"])
def get_prefix_v3(name):
    parts = []
    last_name_found = False
    for part in name.split(" "):
        if part in valid_prefix_parts:
            last_name_found = True
            parts.append(part)
        else:
            prefixes = list(filter(lambda prefix: part.startswith(prefix), valid_prefix_parts))
            if any(prefixes):
                parts.append(prefixes[0])
            elif last_name_found:
                break
    return " ".join(parts)
```

Comment: yes, but the main part of the name also can be lower

Comment: I also add some possible variances of last names from some profiles

Comment: get_prefix_v2 return only 'der' for 'van der Vulpen - Odijk' instead 'van der'

Comment: @Nick Check `get_prefix_v3`